# MasterSuite in Play 2.5 with ScalaTest / ScalaTestPlus

Tags: scala, playframework, scalatest

I would like to create a MasterSuite Test class which creates a Fakeapplication to make my tests faster.

The example in docs of GuiceApplicationBuilder don't compile. Am I missing some magic import?

```
import play.api.test._
import org.scalatest._
import org.scalatestplus.play._
import play.api.{ Play, Application }
import play.api.inject.guice._
import org.scalatestplus.play.guice.GuiceOneAppPerSuite

// This is the "master" suite
class NestedExampleSpec extends Suites(
  new OneSpec,
  new TwoSpec
) with GuiceOneAppPerSuite {
  // Override app if you need an Application with other than non-default parameters.
  def fakeApplication(): Application =
    new GuiceApplicationBuilder().configure(Map("ehcacheplugin" -> "disabled")).build()

}

// These are the nested suites
@DoNotDiscover class OneSpec extends FunSuite with ConfiguredApp
@DoNotDiscover class TwoSpec extends FunSuite with ConfiguredApp
```

Comment: Seems, like it was a wrong documentation.
Everything working now, if I configure the app with
```override lazy val app:Application``` instead of 
```def fakeApplication():Application```

Answer (score 0):

take off:
**import org.scalatestplus.play.guice.GuiceOneAppPerSuite**, at least for me Not find that import in play 2.5.x

the right import:
**import play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder**

the implicit values:

```
implicit lazy val app: play.api.Application = new GuiceApplicationBuilder().configure().build()

implicit lazy val materializer: Materializer = app.materializer
```

an example running [a test suite in playFramework 2.5.x using it](https://github.com/ldipotetjob/restfulinplay/blob/master/modules/apirest/test/com/ldg/play/test/PremierActionsSpec.scala)